# Java Programming help

Tags: java

I have a method that returns Sets of sets. 
Following is what I mean:

```
public static HashSet methodName(){
 HashSet c= new HashSet(); 

 c.add(x); //x is a HashSet of number
 c.add(y); //y is a Hashset of numbers

 return c;
}
```

After the method returns the collections, I enter it into an arraylist

```
ArrayList<HashSet> xxx= new ArrayList<Hashset>();
y=methodName();
xxx.add(y);
```

The method gets called couple of times and each time I enter sets of sets into the arraylist.

My question is. now I want to go through the arraylist and find the set that contains the smallest number of sets. How do I do that? Thanks so much in advance. Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A simple way you to go through an array is through an `Iterator`.  These are utilized in a foreach loop, which can be used when you know the type of elements used in an array (via generics). You can use that in your outer `HashSet`- containing `ArrayList`:

```
for (HashSet set : xxx) {
    // you need to iterate over the elements in your HashSet here and determine which internal Set has the most elements
    for ( Iterator iter = set.iterator(); iter.hasNext();) {
        HashSet innerSet = (HashSet) iter.next();
        // do the size test
     }

}
```

Comment: can you please show me the whole code. How would you compare the size

Comment: `HashSet smallest = null; for (HashSet currentSet : xxx) {if (smallest == null || smallest.size() > currentSet.size()) smallest = currentSet;}`

Answer (score 2):

The `size()` method gives the cardinality of a `HashSet`. Simply write a [`Comparator<HashSet>`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Comparator.html) and use [`Collections.max()`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html#max%28java.util.Collection,%20java.util.Comparator%29).